# How to read file, set value as custom directory in rtorrent?

Tags: xml-rpc, bittorrent, libtorrent

I am trying to get the contents of a txt file and set that content as a custom move directory for rtorrent. Here is what I have in rtorrent.rc:

```
system.method.insert = d.get_loaded_basename,string|simple,"execute_capture=bash,-c,\"cat /files/id.txt\",cleanbase,$d.get_loaded_file="

# insert another method to concatenate the final destination directory with the basename
system.method.insert = d.get_meta_path,simple,"cat=/files/complete/,$d.get_loaded_basename="

#watch and set custom path
schedule = watch_1,15,15,"load_start=/files/watch/*.torrent,d.set_custom1=$d.get_meta_path="

#move file to custom path and execute script
system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,move_complete,"d.set_directory=$d.set_custom1=;execute=mv,-u,$d.get_base_path=,$d.set_custom1=;execute=/files/script.sh {pass ID#}"
```

The id.txt file has a number, for example 123. So for this case the files should be moved to /files/complete/123/. The number in id.txt varies. Also, I want to pass the ID number to script.sh as a argument. How can I achieve this?